# How to delete ZFS snapshots in bulk and upgrading to non LTS version?

Tags: backup, lts, 21.04, zfs, snapshot

Two question.....

1. I have installed Ubuntu LTS 20.04.3 with ZFS and encryption, few hours ago, but don't know how to delete snapshots as they are piling up pretty quickly, I'm setting up my installation, installed zfs-auto-snapshot package but it's not detecting the snapshots for some reason on

`$sudo zfs-auto-snapshot --keep NUM`

No matter what number I give it's says no snapshots detected or sth like that, also skimmed through ZFS manpage but there was only method of deleting snapshots one by one which is very tedious as I have already like 15/20 snapshots piled up....

**So what's the method/solution I should use to tackle it??**

2. Though I moved to LTS version by now, I want the non LTS version, so is there anyway I can achieve that from LTS version to non LTS version a smooth shift without messing anything up?

Comment: I found this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-2271/gbcxl/index.html  perhaps something may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list ZFS snapshots in the terminal with the following command:

```
zfs list -t snapshot
```

To remove a specific snapshot, you can do this:

```
sudo zfs destroy rpool/USERDATA/MHT@FRIDAY09-03-21
```

If you would like to remove *all* snapshots — *damn the torpedoes!* — you can do this:

```
sudo zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot | xargs -n1 zfs destroy
```

Be careful when issuing `zfs destroy` commands, because there is no undo.

As for your second question, the window to upgrade from 20.04 ⇢ 20.10 ⇢ 21.04 has closed, as 20.10 is no longer supported. The simplest way to get your machine up to 21.04 would be to reinstall the OS using the newer installation `.iso`.

Comment: I know, I can delete specific snapshots with these commands but I wanna delete all snapshots in one go or more than one as they pile up pretty quickly

Comment: I generally do not share the "damn the torpedoes" command to remove all ZFS snapshots, because this almost always results in people holding *me* accountable for their impatience later. However, there you go. **Note:** I offer no warranty with this answer.

Comment: I get `no datasets available` on the first command. (yes, I am on a ZFS ubuntu)

Comment: I keep getting annot destroy snapshots: permission denied and the are about 100's of these to delete one at a time.  After deleting about 50, the remaining space amount has not changed at all.  There has to be a better way to get this done.

Comment: If you are receiving permission denied errors, then it usually means that there's a missing `sudo` in front of the command or you're trying to do things with a ZFS volume that was created elsewhere and not fully brought into the current system 

Comment: @HarlanNelson Same here. I used sudo. Even removing zsys does not solve anything, the snapshots are still there. I was not able to upgrade the system for weeks, because I ran out of space. I might install a different OS, Ubuntu is like using Win7 without security patches at its current state. No updates = no support. And these are the defaults for a 1 year old install...

Comment: The proper code is `sudo zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot | sudo xargs -n1 zfs destroy`. It still does not remove everything because of dependencies between snapshots, but removed enough to update the system. Not sure how much it damaged booting though. Maybe I won't be able to boot, we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the error `Error: The filesystem argument list is empty.` by listing the filesystem you want to remove snapshots for. As an example:

```
zfs-auto-snapshot --destroy-only -k 1 --label=hourly rpool/USERDATA
```

This command won't remove any snapshots created manually or snapshots created by zsys.

To upgrade to the latest normal Ubuntu release, you can use the following:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Prompt=.*/Prompt=normal/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
sudo do-release-upgrade
```